# What is the use of transitive field in ivy xml's dependency tag?

Tags: xml, ivy

I have tried searching for it but I did not find any satisfactory answer so I am posting this question. If you have a doc that can explain this in detail, do let me know.

I have this line in my ivy xml:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.3.2" transitive="false" />
```

I don't understand what this transitive field is there for. I am working on an already build project, and I had to add new jars. So I followed the same pattern as its already there. 
I tried removing this "transitive" field and nothing in my project changed. Then I changed it to true. Again, no changes. What is this used for?
Is this the reason why it is downloading all the 3 : source, javadoc and jar for any particular jar? Is it ok to remove this field from my ivy xml if removing it doesn't affect my project?

The apache website says : "true to resolve dependencies transitively, false otherwise" which doesn't clear my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it in a clean workspace (with no dependencies yet).
Also, `commons-lang3` may not be a good example to see what `transtive` does, since it does not in itself depend on any other libraries.

---

From the `Example` section of the [official document](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html) (highlights mine):

```
<dependency org="foo" name="bar" revision="3.0" transitive="false" conf="default->@;runtime,test->runtime"/>
```

Declares a dependency on the module `bar` from foo, in revision 3.0.

**The dependencies of `bar` will themselves not be included** due to the setting of `transitive`.

Answer (score 1):

set transitive="true" to resolve this dependency transitively, false otherwise.
Default value is true.
`<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core"
               rev="3.3.1.GA" transitive="true" />` 
for above dependency ivy downloads all dependent jars of "hibernate-core" as transitive is set to "true". If it false, ivy does not download those dependencies.

Comment: This is only true if the configuration you are building against doesn't set the global transitive value itself (see transitive https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0/ivyfile/conf.html ). If it does then that value takes precedence over the dependency's transitive value.